# is there a data structure with the following properties:

Tags: data-structures

given n elements, the datastructure has the following runtime complexities:

Finding the minimum element is Θ(1),
Deleting the minimum element is Θ(lg n)

Inserting an element is Θ(lg n)

i made research, i dont know this fast data structure

Comment: min-heap maybe? First thing that comes to my mind.

Comment: maybe a tree implementation of a symbol table, but not sure

Comment: That sounds like a heap, but I might be missing something because you would easily have found it

Comment: Red-black trees, actually most balanced trees, should have these properties too.

Comment: @justin: yes min-heap is the right answer, you should put this as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

```
Operation       Binary      Binomial    Fibonacci
find-min        Θ(1)        Θ(1)        Θ(1)
delete-min      Θ(log n)    Θ(log n)    O(log n)*
insert          Θ(log n)    O(log n)    Θ(1)
decrease-key    Θ(log n)    Θ(log n)    Θ(1)*
merge           Θ(n)        O(log n)**  Θ(1)
(*) Amortized time
(**) Where n is the size of the larger heap
```

Comment: now this is clear, i read the article, it just describes the operations vry simply!